# Isapi redirect dll for IIS 10

Tags: isapi

Is isap_redirect.1.2.40.dll compatible with IIS 10? 
I am trying to start integrating iis 10 with tomcat 9.0.31 and looking for the right dll to be used?

Comment: did you try already ? Your question sounds as if you had problems already ? Otherwise, I advise you look at the documentation for dll version references.

Comment: I didnt however I need to confirm which one is the appropriate before start to not run into problems.

Comment: I tried integrating using iis to tomcat with isapi redirect dll 1.2.48  and followed the steps as per tomcat documentation however I still have issues and unable to make integration success. verified and validated numerous times. Installed/unstalled and performed the steps but in vein.

Comment: Any help/guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: There is not much one can do to help you without any log and details about what you did and what happens. I think you should prepare that, and maybe ask on https://serverfault.com/